# Looking for a translation for the German "hellhörig"/"ringhörig"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, translation

The German adjective "*[hellhörig](https://www.dict.cc/german-english/hellh%C3%B6rig.html)*" (sometimes also "*ringhörig*") describes a badly or insufficiently soundproofed building or room; i.e. being able to hear your neighbors through the walls because the walls are so thin.

What's an equivalent English adjective for that?

Comment: The room is either 'noisy' or 'neighbourly' depending on how friendly one is with the aforesaid neighbours.

Comment: The hyperbolic "The walls are paper thin" is sometimes heard.

Comment: Google translate gives the perfectly legitimate "poorly soundproofed".

Comment: Google Books has many written instances of [***thin-walled** apartment*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22thin-walled+apartment%22) - where in nearly every case the primary implication (the reason for mentioning it at all) is probably that if you lived there you could *hear your neighbors through the walls.*

Comment: You could try *auralistic*, and see if it catches on?